# Android Webview/Activity Interaction

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Is there a way to say if an activity is selected then do something?

I dont know the statement which is why i am asking this question, but similar to this:

```
if(myactivity.isselected(true)){
webview3.reload();}
```

Comment: What do you think "an activity is selected" means? That phrase has no particular meaning in Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thats why I am asking, I dont know what the statement would be. I have 3 tabs with a separate activity in each one and I want to refresh the webview I am COMING FROM when I select a new tab.

Comment: I made that snippet of code up to help you guys understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using tabs, then onTabChange() is the correct event for that. Not all tabs are individual activities. Not even necessarily different layouts. Then you can check to see if the selected tab is the activity like this

public void onTabChange(View v, int id) {
switch (v.getId()) {
   case (R.id.tab1) {
       //Do this
       break;
   }
}

The tabhost supports alot of functionality. Another funcitonis getTab() which will return the id (as an int) of the tab selected. Heres a link to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Comment: But all tabs are different activities, I made it that way on purpose. The problem with this is that it does not recognize the webviews when I use onTabChange because they are all specified inside of their own respective class so I need a different method for this

Comment: From reading what your trying to prevent from happening is the music stopping when the screen locks. You may want to try researching services. Thats the only things I can think of that would accomplish this. Find some way to stream your flash content through a service?

Answer (score 0):

When user moves through different user interface , he/she start different activities. Since you have different tabs, you should have three different screens and so three different activities , if user is moving from one tab to another, you should first pause the initial activity and should start other activity.

Comment: I do not want to do that because it is a webview with a flash music player in it. Flash content overlaps the new tab so I need to reload the previous webview to get rid of that problem. The onPause method works, but I want to use a different method because then the music stops playing when the user's screen locks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the activities that the tabhost is running, with this:

```
YourActivity act = (YourActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(TABKEY_1);
```

then call any method you have in that activity. TABKEY_1 is just the name for the tab that you give when you initialized the tabhost.